How to find which dependency cause the pnpm warn unmet peer?
Had read [pnpm] unmet peer search result in stackoverflow.
I'm a little curious about what dependencies used postcss in version 5.2.
Any tips for finding it? There was a long warning each time
─┬ postcss-preset-env 9.6.0
│ ├── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-color-function 3.0.19
│ │ ├── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ │ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-progressive-custom-properties 3.3.0
│ │ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ │ └─┬ @csstools/utilities 1.0.0
│ │   └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-font-format-keywords 3.0.2
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-hwb-function 3.0.18
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-ic-unit 3.0.7
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-exponential-functions 1.0.9
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-gamut-mapping 1.0.11
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-content-alt-text 1.0.0
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-light-dark-function 1.0.8
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-color-mix-function 2.0.19
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-is-pseudo-class 4.0.8
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-cascade-layers 4.0.6
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-logical-overflow 1.0.1
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-gradients-interpolation-method 4.0.20
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-logical-resize 2.0.1
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-media-minmax 1.1.8
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18
│ ├─┬ @csstools/postcss-logical-viewport-units 2.0.11
│ │ └── ✕ unmet peer postcss@^8.4: found 5.2.18


No ending, toooooo long ......

